# How can I achieve a "anyOf" requirement with Annotations in C# for the Newtonsoft Json Schema Generator?

Tags: c#, json.net, generator, jsonschema

I want to set Annotations in my C# class so that the Newtonsoft Json Schema Generator can create a Schema out of that class automatically. In that Class I set [Required]-attributes to determine which properties are required in the schema and which are not. Here a quick example:

```
[Required] public string Name { get; set; }
```

I now sometimes have groups of Properties where only one of them (but no specific one) should be required. I know, that I can achieve this in JSON Schema by using "anyOf" / "oneOf", but I couldn't find an attribute that I can write in my C# Code so that the JSON Schema Generator would generate an "anyOf". Does anyone know how to do this? Or is there a workaround? To clarify, a c# example:

```
class destination{
    [Required] int id;

    //only of those two should be required
    [Required] string address;
    [Required] string coordinates;
}
```

This should somehow be generated to a JSON Schema like this:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties":{
        "id": {"type": "integer"},
        "address": {"type": "string"},
        "coordinates": {"type": "string"}
    },
    "anyOf"[
        {"required": ["id","address"]},
        {"required": ["id","coordinates"]},
    ]
}
```

thanks in advance!
Freddie

Comment: I don't think Json.NET schema has support for generating `"anyOf"` requirements automatically via annotations, see [anyOf, allOf, oneOf, not #120](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues/120).  You probably need to write a custom [`JSchemaGenerationProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateWithProvider.htm), see e.g. [How can I create a custom JSchemaGenerationProvider that adds a title attribute to both the model and to the model's properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36410480/3744182).

Comment: If a `JSchemaGenerationProvider` would meet your needs, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing a class for which you want to generate a schema, and the resulting schema you want to generate?  See: [ask].